# URL in rails 2.3.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys!
How possible can make link like this: `http://localhost:3000/questiond_id=5&token=734893789568495` (there will be only one question (form) and token (unique) for them and that all)

? in routers.rb ? Or where?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In rails you can access like this:

```
 http://localhost:3000/questions/5?token=734893789568495
```

In routes.rb file

```
 resources :questions
```

You can restrict this by only option if you don't want other actions.

For this, you can use show action of questions controller and your path will be like this

```
 question_path(:id => 5, :token => '734893789568495')
```